# mapping controllers without annotations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to do mapping in Spring/Spring-boot to controllers without anno's on controllers?

In Grails I was able to write a completely abstracted api without api functionality, checks, annotations on the controller. This allows for all functionality and data to be handled in the front controller through handlerInterceptor... and controller merely has to create resource. This also makes it easier to share functionality/data for api across I/O flow in architecture.

How do we map request to controller/method without annotations? There must be a way since it can be done in Grails.

Comment: Check out [`BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html).

Comment: Check this [springmvc-router](https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router) project.

Comment: Actually I want to manually add mappings to controllers not necessarily actually 'map' the controllers. Thus i would need manual control over setting the mappings. BeanNameHandlerMapping wants to set things a particular way.

Comment: I think what I may be looking for is 'ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping' along with 'InternalPathMethodNameResolver'

Comment: Ok so I am pretty sure the answer is that you have to just check them at handlerInterceptor which was what my plan was and load them in config. Going to test and see if this works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put below tag in your bean configuration file. This will scan your controller class in your base package. Just define package name where you put your controller classes.

```
<beans 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

    <context:component-scan  base-package=" " />

</beans>
```

As for example -

You have controller class called controller1, controller2 in com.pacakge.controller.demo1
and controller3, controller4 in com.pacakge.controller.demo2

here your code -

```
 <context:component-scan  base-package="com.pacakge.controller" />
```